# parameters jquery and the HTML 5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I currently am working with the html canvas to take user input and make text bold with in the canvas. I developed the following code to do this:

```
var bodyFontString = "14px Arial";
function makeBold(pText){
pText = ("bold"+" "+pText);

}
makeBold(bodyFontString);
context.font = bodyFontString;
context.fillText("hello", 20, 20)
```

The idea is to replace the string that would be assigned to context.font with a string that contains the new bold language. For some reason I can't make this work. Please help.

Comment: No that is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually changing anything:

```
var bodyFontString = "14px Arial";

function makeBold(pText){
    return ("bold"+" "+pText); /// return result
}

context.font = makeBold(bodyFontString); /// use result
context.fillText("hello", 20, 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're not setting `context.font` in `makeBold`. All `makeBold` does is change the value of the parameter `pText`.

Here's what's happening:

```
makeBold(bodyFontString); // Doesn't set context.font to anything!
context.font = bodyFontString; // Sets context.font to the original value, without the bold
```

Try this:

```
function makeBold(pText) {
    return "bold " + pText;
}

context.font = makeBold(bodyFontString);
context.fillText("hello", 20, 20)
```